# If a sequence converges then the sequence is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

I am taking an online real analysis class. In the class on sequences and series, the professor said the above statement is true since when a series converges to a point it is bounded in its neighborhood.

But 1/(n-2) is clearly a series that converges to 0 but is not bounded in the neighborhood of 2. (considering n to be a rational number). Since many pointed out that the series is not defined at 2. I am defining it to be 0 for n=2. So it seems like I am missing something here. Or is the above statement false?

Here is the link to the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VEx3Ys6JAJo&list=PL0E754696F72137EC&index=15

Comment: In what sense is 1/n not bounded? It is always between 0 and 1.

Comment: Explain why you think $1/n$ is not bounded, please.

Comment: if I consider 1/n for n from 0 to infinity.

Comment: $1/n$ is not defined for $n=0$.

Comment: It's for $n=1,2,3,\dots$  $1/n$ is not defined when $n=0$.

Comment: "It takes the value infinity" is what you are missing : a sequence has terms that are real numbers (not to be confused with a limit being infinite) so for $n=5$ if you "define" the sequence as infinite then the sequence is not a real sequence anymore.

Comment: @saulspatz Okay, But what if I define it to be infinity for n=0. I can choose to define it that way or can't I?

Comment: Maybe you're confusing the sequence with the series.  The series adds up to infinity but the sequence converges to $0$.

Comment: No.  See the comment from @TeresaLisbon.

Comment: @UtkarshRaj You *cannot define any particular term as infinite*. In particular, if you have something like $a_n = \frac 1{n-5}$ or so then this sequence is not well-defined at $n=5$ so you have to work around that.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thanks that clears it up. So what about 1/(n-2). It is not defined at 2. And here n is a real number. so is this function bounded? In the neighbourhood of 2 approaches infinity.

Comment: @UtkarshRaj This function is not defined at $2$, but is unbounded in a neighbourhood of $2$, as you say. Creating the sequence $\frac 1{n-2}$ risks non-definition at $n=2$ so you must create a new value there.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon. But what about in the neighbourhood of 2? I am considering n to be a real number here.

Comment: It can be defined there (apart from $2$), but will be unbounded in any neighbourhood of $2$.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I was thinking. So clearly this sequence converges but is not bounded. So does that mean that the claim "If a sequence converges then the sequence is bounded?" is false?

Comment: What sequence are you talking about? A sequence has the form $x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots$. You seem to be confusing the concept of function (the function $1\over n-2$) with some sequence where $x_i$ is $1\over y_i-2$ for some values $y_i$. (You also use the word “sequence” in your title but say some things about series. Sequences, series, and functions are different things with different definitions of “converge.”)

Comment: @SteveKass yeah and here that sequence is the sequence of points defined by (1/(n-2)) for all rationals n. Clearly, rationals are countable so this should still be a sequence right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the definition of a sequence. A sequence is a countable list of real numbers (possibly finite or infinite). Thats it. It has a $1$ term, a $2$ term, a $3$ term, and so on.

When you say: what about the sequence $\frac{1}{n-2}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, at $n=2$? The answer is that this is not a sequence. In fact, it is a sequence for $n\geq 3$, but you cannot call an undefined value as part of a sequence.

But you say, what about the sequence $\frac{1}{n-2}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{R}^+$ except for $n=2$? You are correct, this **function** is unbounded around $n=2$. However, a sequence takes as inputs natural numbers, not real numbers. Thus, what you have described is again not a sequence.

I think a main point you are misunderstanding is that generally, $n$ is taken to be a natural number. That is, $n\in\mathbb{N}$. It is sloppy notation to define a sequence as $a_n=\frac{1}{n-2}$ without also saying what happens at $n=2$. However, mathematicians will generally just ignore this undefined term (or let it be $0$).

---

But you say, what if you let $n$ run over all rational numbers except for $2$? Well, then what we are really doing is defining

$$a_n=\frac{1}{b_n-2}$$

where $b_n$ is any enumeration of the rationals except for $2$. But then this sequence does not converge. Let $M>0$ be given. Then there is some $k$ such that

$$b_k=\frac{4\lceil M\rceil+1}{2\lceil M\rceil}$$

Then

$$a_k=\frac{1}{b_k-2}=\frac{1}{\frac{4\lceil M\rceil+1}{2\lceil M\rceil}-2}=2\lceil M\rceil>M$$

Thus, the sequence does not converge. That is, the sequence definately converges (ignoring the issue at $n=2$) if $n$ goes over the naturals. However, if $n$ runs over some other countable set then the sequence may not converge.

Comment: For n =2, I am defining the sequence to have the value 0. So considering 1/(n-2) where n is all rational number >0. The sequence is not bounded yet defined at all points. And it does converge to 0 or does it?

Comment: @QC.  I have modified the question to include only rational numbers. And since rational numbers are countable, we should be able to construct a sequence out of them. Isn't that right?

Comment: Thanks that was greatly helpful.

Comment: "That is, the sequence definitely converges (ignoring the issue at n=2) if n goes over the rationals,"   I think you meant the sequence doesn't converge if n goes over all rational.

Comment: Yes, fixed it to "naturals"

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $s_{n}$ converges to $s$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Then there exists $N$ such that $|s_{n} - s| < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. This means $s_{n} \in (s - \epsilon, s + \epsilon)$ for all $n \geq N$.

Comment: But what about the sequence 1/(n-2) for all real n >0. The sequence is not defined at 2 but is clearly not bounded in the neighbourhood of 2 yet the series converges to 0.

Comment: Does it converge to 2? If you look at the answer I have given, the neighborhood you should be talking about is the neighborhood around the limit. The tail of the sequence lies in that neighborhood.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is the standard proof of such result.

**Proposition**

Let $x_{n}\in\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence which converges to $x_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$, then it is bounded.

**Proof**

Let $\varepsilon = 1$. Then, according to the definition of limit, there exists $n_{1}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{align*}
n\geq n_{1} \Rightarrow |x_{n} - x_{0}| < 1 \Rightarrow |x_{n}| - |x_{0}| < 1 \Rightarrow |x_{n}| < |x_{0}| + 1
\end{align*}

Thus, if we take $M = \max\{|x_{1}|,|x_{2}|,\ldots,|x_{n_{1}-1}|,|x_{0}| + 1\}$, we can conclude that $|x_{n}| \leq M$.

That is to say $x_{n}$ is bounded, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Yeah, I get the proof part. What i am struggling to see is for the above example why is it that the sequence 1/(n-2) for all rational >0 the sequence is bounded?